# RPC response exceeds maximum data length in Hadoop

Tags: apache, hadoop, hadoop2

I am trying to configure hadoop from **[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_mapreduce.htm][1].**
I have configured everything.Now at the time of execution command **$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar /home/abp/unit/unit.jar com.hadoop.ProcessUnits input_dir output_dir** 
I have getting below exception

```
abp@abp-Precision-T1700:/usr/local/hadoop/bin$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar /home/abp/unit/unit.jar com.hadoop.ProcessUnits input_dir output_dir 
17/04/26 15:09:09 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/04/26 15:09:10 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
17/04/26 15:09:10 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response exceeds maximum data length; Host Details : local host is: "abp-Precision-T1700/127.0.1.1"; destination host is: "localhost":9000; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:782)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1485)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:787)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:335)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1700)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$27.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$27.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:141)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1338)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1807)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:575)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:570)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1807)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:570)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:561)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:870)
    at com.hadoop.ProcessUnits.main(ProcessUnits.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response exceeds maximum data length
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$IpcStreams.readResponse(Client.java:1800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:1155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:1052)

Please help me in resolving this.
```

Comment: can you once verify that everything is up and running using JPS command

Comment: abp@abp-Precision-T1700:/usr/local/hadoop/bin$ jps
8445 ResourceManager
9986 Jps
3518 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
abp@abp-Precision-T1700:/usr/local/hadoop/bin$

Comment: have you started your dfs because there is no namenode and datanode is running in the system so that's why you are not able to connect.

Comment: run start-dfs.sh command to start namenode and datanode service

Comment: i have run start-all.sh command

Comment: may be there will be problem with your configuration in core-site.xml file so can you please share once core-site.xml and also log file of namenode.

Comment: <configuration>
<property>
      <name>fs.default.name</name>
      <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
   </property>
</configuration>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142726/discussion-between-hari-singh-and-biswajit).

Comment: Might be a problem with the port number you are using. Try this : <https://stackoverflow.com/a/60701948/8504709>