# Exception ": org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response exceeds maximum data length" from java

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to connect to remote HDFS from Java program running in my desktop's Eclipse. I am able to connect. But get this Exception while trying to read data:

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response exceeds maximum data

Can some one please help with this?

I have a very basic code for reading test data.Error is coming from hdfs.open();

```
FileSystem hdfs =null;
    String uriPath = "hdfs://" + Constants.HOST + ":" + Constants.PORT+ "/test/hello_world.txt";
    String hadoopBase ="hdfs://" + Constants.HOST + ":" + Constants.PORT;
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("fs.default.name", hadoopBase);
    URI uri;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        uri = new URI(uriPath);
        hdfs =  FileSystem.get(uri, conf);
        Path path = new Path(uri);
        inputStream = hdfs.open(path);
        IOUtils.copyBytes(inputStream, System.out, 4096, false);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            hdfs.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        IOUtils.closeStream(inputStream);
    }
```

Here is the full Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response exceeds maximum data length; 
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:785)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1485)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1427)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1337)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:227)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:255)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:398)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:163)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:155)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:335)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:826)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:815)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:804)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.fetchLocatedBlocksAndGetLastBlockLength(DFSInputStream.java:319)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.openInfo(DFSInputStream.java:281)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.<init>(DFSInputStream.java:270)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:1115)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$4.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:325)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$4.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:321)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:333)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:786)
at DataUtil.readData(DataUtil.java:29)
at main(Main.java:24)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response exceeds maximum data length
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$IpcStreams.readResponse(Client.java:1800)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:1155)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:1052)
```

Comment: some code around the the section where error happens will be helpful.

Comment: Try to set a bigger buffSize and see if it would change anything, probably because you are reading bigger data than your inputstream can handle, hope it will help

Answer (score 7):

Check your **core-site.xml** :

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://host:port</value>
</property>
```

This port can be **9000** or **8020**.
Make sure that you are using the **same port in your code or command**

Answer (score 1):

try this solution:
add this config to hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
     <name>ipc.maximum.data.length</name>
     <value>134217728</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to check the real response data length in the namenode.log of the active namenode.
The message must be like :

```
WARN org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Large response size 786010791 for call Call#3
```

After you know the response data length you can change the parameter ipc.maximum.response.length accordingly to the real size.

BTW the issue may be on the client side, as was in my case. So just add the parameter to the client core-site.xml or directly to the command.
For example:

```
hadoop distcp -D ipc.maximum.response.length=1073741824 ...
```