# OOZIE: JA009: RPC response exceeds maximum data length

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop, oozie

OOZIE wordcount example gives JA009: RPC response exceeds maximum data length. We have doubled the ipc.maximum.data.length and restarted the NameNode.

```
2018-12-05 17:55:45,914  WARN MapReduceActionExecutor:523 - SERVER[******] USER[******] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000004-181205174411487-oozie-******-W] ACTION[0000004-181205174411487-oozie-******-W@mr-node] No credential properties found for action : 0000004-181205174411487-oozie-******-W@mr-node, cred : null
2018-12-05 18:10:46,019  WARN ActionStartXCommand:523 - SERVER[******] USER[******] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000004-181205174411487-oozie-******-W] ACTION[0000004-181205174411487-oozie-******-W@mr-node] Error starting action [mr-node]. ErrorType [TRANSIENT], ErrorCode [JA009], Message [JA009: RPC response exceeds maximum data length]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: JA009: RPC response exceeds maximum data length
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertExceptionHelper(ActionExecutor.java:463)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertException(ActionExecutor.java:437)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:1512)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:243)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:68)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:290)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:334)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:263)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:181)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response exceeds maximum data length
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$IpcStreams.readResponse(Client.java:1808)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:1163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:1059)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Might be a problem with the port number you are using. Try this : <https://stackoverflow.com/a/60701948/8504709>

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to modify the config in hdfs-site.xml?

```
<property>
     <name>ipc.maximum.data.length</name>
     <value>134217728</value>
</property>
```

If it is already high enough, then make sure that core-site.xml configuration for fs.default.name is using the ip not just localhost.

```
<configuration>
       ....
        <property>
                <name>fs.default.name</name>
                <value>hdfs://your ip:9000</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Currently we are using this config:
    <name>ipc.maximum.data.length</name>
    <value>134217728</value>
And in core-site.xml we are using ip. Although our hadoop cluster is HA so we have tried this too.
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://clustername</value>

Comment: Also in oozie, what are the configurations we need to set.

Comment: Are you sure your namenode is up ? what do you get when you run JPS ?

Comment: Yes NameNode and all the DataNodes are up. I have double checked it from jps as well as from the http://myip:50070