# How to fix "RPC response exceeds maximum data length" error while trying to read from hdfs using tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to read a csv file from hdfs using tensorflow. But I am encountering this error.

I had tried this: [OOZIE: JA009: RPC response exceeds maximum data length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633054/oozie-ja009-rpc-response-exceeds-maximum-data-length) But it's not working for me.

Here's my tensorflow code.

```
import tensorflow as tf

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["hdfs://192.168.60.41:50070/DLTest-3k.csv"])

reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)


with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Start populating the filename queue.
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  id, val = sess.run([key, value])
  for v in val.splitlines():
    print(v.decode())

  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
```

hadoop version

```
WARNING: HADOOP_PREFIX has been replaced by HADOOP_HOME. Using value of HADOOP_PREFIX.
Hadoop 3.1.1
Source code repository Unknown -r Unknown
Compiled by root on 2019-07-19T06:28Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum f76ac55e5b5ff0382a9f7df36a3ca5a0
This command was run using /root/hadoop-3.1.1-src/hadoop-dist/target/hadoop-3.1.1/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.1.1.jar
```

Python version: 3.5.2

Tensorflow version: 1.14.0

This is the error message I am receiving.

```
    2019-07-22 09:54:50,474 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2019-07-22 09:54:51,932 WARN net.NetUtils: Unable to wrap exception of type class org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: it has no (String) constructor
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException.<init>(java.lang.String)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:830)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:806)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1501)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1443)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1353)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:317)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:856)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:845)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:834)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:998)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$4.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$4.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:334)
hdfsOpenFile(/DLTest-3k.csv): FileSystem#open((Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;I)Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream;) error:
RpcException: RPC response exceeds maximum data lengthjava.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response exceeds maximum data length; Host Details : local host is: "f35daeba55f7/172.17.0.3"; destination host is: "bigbraindev.razorthink.net":50070; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:816)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1501)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1443)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1353)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:317)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:856)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:845)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:834)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:998)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$4.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$4.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:334)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response exceeds maximum data length
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$IpcStreams.readResponse(Client.java:1816)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:1167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:1063)
2019-07-22 09:54:51.969178: W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:277] _0_input_producer: Skipping cancelled enqueue attempt with queue not closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1356, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1341, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1429, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: hdfs://192.168.60.41:50070/DLTest-3k.csv; Unknown error 255
     [[{{node ReaderReadV2}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    id, val = sess.run([key, value])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 950, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1173, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1370, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: hdfs://192.168.60.41:50070/DLTest-3k.csv; Unknown error 255
     [[node ReaderReadV2 (defined at test.py:6) ]]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node ReaderReadV2:
 WholeFileReaderV2 (defined at test.py:5)   
 input_producer (defined at test.py:3)

Original stack trace for 'ReaderReadV2':
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/io_ops.py", line 166, in read
    return gen_io_ops.reader_read_v2(self._reader_ref, queue_ref, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 1105, in reader_read_v2
    queue_handle=queue_handle, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3616, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2005, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

Comment: Might be a problem with the port number you are using. Try this : <https://stackoverflow.com/a/60701948/8504709>