# MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException RPC response exceeds maximum data length)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

i am using Hive with MYSQL and i can create database with MYSQL but every time i try to create database with hive i get the below error:

hive> create database trainingsession;
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException RPC response exceeds maximum data length)

i have ran the follow 2 commands but its not working

hive> set hive.msck.repair.batch.size=1;
hive> set hive.msck.path.validation=ignore;

please anyone with an idea should assist. thank you

Comment: Can you share your HiveConnectionPool configuration? What version of NiFi and Hive are you using? Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633054/oozie-ja009-rpc-response-exceeds-maximum-data-length , you may be able to update your site config to increase this amount.