# Hadoop | local host is different from destination host

Tags: hadoop, ssh, localhost

I'm trying to set up Hadoop in my local computer and I'm pretty stuck on this one.

```
▶ hadoop fs -mkdir /home/hadoop
mkdir: Failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response exceeds maximum data length; Host Details : local host is: "aleph-pc.local/192.168.1.129"; destination host is: "aleph-pc":8020;
```

I think it has to do with the way I have my sshd configured or the value in `fs.default.name` and it's closely related to this other [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085827/hadoop-giving-error-ls-failed-on-local-exception-org-apache-hadoop-ipc-rpcexc). Where can I go from here? I'd appreciate any help.

```
▶ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost

▶ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.9.2
Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r 826afbeae31ca687bc2f8471dc841b66ed2c6704
Compiled by ajisaka on 2018-11-13T12:42Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 3a9939967262218aa556c684d107985
This command was run using /home/aleph/Documents/Projects/Hadoop/hadoop-2.9.2/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.9.2.jar

▶ tail hadoop-2.9.2/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml 
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
    <property>                                                                                    
        <name>fs.default.name</name>                                                              
        <value>hdfs://aleph-pc/127.0.0.1</value>
    </property>      


</configuration>

▶ jps
17619 Main
32133 NodeManager
32037 ResourceManager
31879 SecondaryNameNode
17816 RemoteMavenServer36
1020 Jps
31678 DataNode
```

Comment: `hdfs://aleph-pc/127.0.0.1` should just be `hdfs://aleph-pc`. Also, appears the NameNode never started, so you should check its log file

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: Might be a problem with the port number you are using. Try this : <https://stackoverflow.com/a/60701948/8504709>