# How to read remote HDFS parquets from my local PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I am trying to load data from a remote HDFS file system to my local PySpark session on my local Mac machine:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

path = "/xx/yy/order_info_20220413/partn_date=20220511/part-00085-dd.gz.parquet"
host = "host"
port = 1234
orders = spark.read.parquet(
    f"hdfs://{host}:{port}{path}"
)
```

Here is the error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o55.parquet.
: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response exceeds maximum data length
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$IpcStreams.readResponse(Client.java:1936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:1238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:1134)
```

I tried to understand what `RPC response exceeds maximum data length` is. I DID NOT find anything similar to the code block in `core-site.xml` as what https://stackoverflow.com/a/60701948/6693221 shows:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://host:port</value>
</property>
```

However, when I typed `telnet host port` in my Mac OS terminal, I was CONNECTED. What is the solution?

Comment: If you get an RPC response error usually means you've connected to an open port, but it's not the correct one... Your code here is correct, though, you're just using the wrong address

Answer (score 0):

You sould configure your file system before creating the spark session, you can do that in the `core-site.xml` file or directly in your session config, then to read the parquet, you need just to provide the path, where you already configured your session to use the remote hdfs cluster as a FS:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

path = "/xx/yy/order_info_20220413/partn_date=20220511/part-00085-dd.gz.parquet"
host = "host"
port = 1234

spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.default.name", f"hdfs://{host}:{port}")
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS", f"hdfs://{host}:{port}")
    .getOrCreate()
) 

orders = spark.read.parquet(path)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Sorry, I still got the same error message. In your answer`set` should be `config`, I assume?

Comment: can you try with this config `.config("spark.yarn.access.hadoopFileSystems", f"hdfs://{host}:{port}")` ?

Comment: You don't need both default.name and defaultFs

Comment: @HusseinAwala, with this configuration added, I received: `AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/wdc/watsons_daily_data/event_info_20220420/part-00076-95112a64-9479-402d-b312-87caf845d50b.c000.gz.parquet`. I also tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73345801/6693221